# Why does the * xpath abbreviation not include text nodes?

Tags: xpath

In an xpath expression like `$node/*` why are text nodes not included as child nodes? Is this something that is just because that is how xpath is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this something that is just because that is how xpath is defined?

Pretty much. In [section 2.3 of the XPath 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests), it says:

> A node test `*` is true for any node of the principal node type. For example, `child::*` will select all element children of the context node, and `attribute::*` will select all attributes of the context node.

And further, in [section 2.5](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev), it says:

> - `*` selects all element children of the context node

Comment: I would add that `$node/node()` is a shortcut for `$node/child::node()` and does select all kind of child nodes, including text nodes. That seems to be what spig is looking for instead of `$node/*`.

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering why * didn't return all nodes. It seems that is how the spec defines it.

Answer (score 2):

It's very difficult to answer "why" questions. Are you asking a historical question about the process by which the decision was made, e.g. what arguments were advanced both ways and how the voting went? Or are you just asking for a best guess - can anyone think of a reason why a reasonable language designer would have chosen to do it this way? Sometimes when people ask "why" questions, they mean something quite different, like "what rule in the specification says that the language should behave this way?". That's the way @BoltClock has chosen to interpret it. The way you've phrased the question, I find it hard to know which kind of answer you are looking for.

Clearly it could have been done differently; instead of `a/*` selecting all element children and `a/node()` selecting all children of all kinds, it could have been `a/element()` and `a/*` respectively. My guess at the rationale would be that selecting all elements was thought to be a more common user requirement. But of course when language designers use that kind of rationale, they are guessing what users will want to do.

Comment: I was just confused about the * alias. For some reason I thought it returned all nodes and now know that it is only elements. I didn't take the time to dig into the spec but I will in the future.